# Find maximum of a property from one array and pass it to a new array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an object as below

```
[{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810bbd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 8, "WeekId": 1 },
{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 8, "WeekId": 0 },
{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 16, "WeekId": 0 },
{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 24, "WeekId": 0 },
{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 32, "WeekId": 0 },
{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 16, "WeekId": 1 },
{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 24, "WeekId": 1 },
{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 40, "WeekId": 0 },
{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 32, "WeekId": 1 }]
```

What I need to do is find the max of `BucketValue` provided the `ResourceId` and `WeekId` matches

I.e. In above example find max of `BucketValue` if `ResourceId = 11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c` and `WeekId = 0` which comes to `40`.

If `ResourceId = 11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c` and `WeekId = 1`, max will be `32`

I should have a final array as below:

```
[{
    "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c",
    "BucketValue": 40,
    "WeekId": 0
},{
    "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c",
    "BucketValue": 32,
    "WeekId": 1
}]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Have you tried solving it yourself? if yes, please post what you have tried so far. if no, then please try to do it on your own first.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [underscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) for your purpose? A simple `find()` and then a `filter()` may do the trick.

Comment: Good question and many good inputs from the community. Don't mind the downvotes. Please just remember to mark an answer as answer when you are pleased with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you're better off having a function that returns the result of one search and then add that result to a new array, rather than have it return an array of all searches.

```
function findMax(arr, id, week) {

  // if week is not present in any of the objects
  // immediately return false from the function
  if (!arr.some(function (el) { return el.WeekId === week; })) return false;

  // find the max ResourceId value from the data set
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.ResourceId === id && el.WeekId === week;
  }).map(function (el) { return el.BucketValue; }));

  // return the object that has that max ResourceId value
  return arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.BucketValue === max;
  })[0];

}

var arr = [];
arr.push(findMax(data, '11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c', 0));
arr.push(findMax(data, '11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c', 1));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e2swgeLm/13/)

Alternatively you can have the function return an array of all the searches.

```
function findMax(arr, search) {

  var out = [];

  search.forEach(function (item) {

    var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr.filter(function (el) {
      return el.ResourceId === item[0] && el.WeekId === item[1];
    }).map(function (el) {
      return el.BucketValue;
    }));

    var obj = arr.filter(function (el) {
      return el.BucketValue === max;
    })[0];

    out.push(obj);

  });

  return out;

}

var search = [
  ['11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c', 0],
  ['11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c', 1]
];

findMax(data, search);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/68z41tLn/1/)

**EDIT**

If you just want to return the max value from the object, rather than the whole object just return `BucketValue` from the filter:

```
function findMax(arr, id, week) {

  // find the max ResourceId value from the data set
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.ResourceId === id && el.WeekId === week;
  }).map(function (el) { return el.BucketValue; }));

  // return the object that has that max ResourceId value
  return arr.filter(function (el) {
    return el.BucketValue === max;
  })[0].BucketValue;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy but can we do this dynamically instead of passing the resource id and week id.That is the loop checks for if the similar resource id and week id exists in resulting array and if it does push the max value of bucket value to it.

Comment: Probably, but that's not what you asked. You said "find max of BucketValue if ResourceId = 11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c and WeekId = 0 which comes to 40." so passing in the ids is implied.

Comment: Thanks a lot , However what changes i can make on  solution 1 you provided to just get the max value for a particular resource and week.That is if I pass resource id and week id I should be getting max value of bucket value

Comment: `[0]` to `[0].BucketValue` on the `filter` section.

Comment: Andy can you please repost the complete code with the changes needed to achieve the result mentioned in comment. I am very new to Javascript and would be thankful if you do so.

Comment: Ok Got it.Thanks a lot Andy!!

Comment: Andy but i dont want the value in array just an integer , that is if I pass a resource id and week id I should get the a single integer value and not in an array . What changes would i need to do so.

Comment: Then don't push the result of the function into an array.

Comment: Andy If I dont have a weekid in array but I pass it Eg : findMax(data, '11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c', 2) ,Here I dont have 2 as weekid but if I pass it what changes do I make to the function to first check it.Currently its giving me an error.

Answer (score 1):

I have two possible solutions for this problem:

Sort the array with [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) descending with `WeekId` as group and take only the first item of every group with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var array = [{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810bb-d4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 8, "WeekId": 1 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 8, "WeekId": 0 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 16, "WeekId": 0 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 24, "WeekId": 0 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 32, "WeekId": 0 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 16, "WeekId": 1 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 24, "WeekId": 1 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 40, "WeekId": 0 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 32, "WeekId": 1 }],
    weekId,        
    result = array.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.WeekId - b.WeekId || b.BucketValue - a.BucketValue;
    }).filter(function (a) {
        if (weekId !== a.WeekId) {
            weekId = a.WeekId;
            return true;
        }
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Or use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and replace in the result set every bigger value with the same `WeekId`.

```js
var array = [{ "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810bb-d4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 8, "WeekId": 1 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 8, "WeekId": 0 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 16, "WeekId": 0 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 24, "WeekId": 0 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 32, "WeekId": 0 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 16, "WeekId": 1 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 24, "WeekId": 1 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 40, "WeekId": 0 }, { "ResourceId": "11a0a500-7e1c-4e2d-810b-bd4401892b7c", "BucketValue": 32, "WeekId": 1 }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        !r.some(function (b, i, bb) {
            if (a.WeekId === b.WeekId) {
                if (a.BucketValue > b.BucketValue) {
                    bb[i] = a;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }) && r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Im new to Js aswell and i cant say i understand your syntax fully. Could you please explain why you use the "," character after your array and after weekid in your first solution?

Comment: @Kodz, it is the repeating declaring of a variable. please have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Declaring_and_initializing_two_variables